# VBA Error Calling Public Function in ElseIf Statement

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a public function on my main form that creates a new record in my subform (located on my mainform). I am trying to call the public function with a Yes/No message box. (Ie: Do you want to update the record? Yes - Creates a new record in the subform. No - Doesn't create a new record).

I am able to call the public function outside of the Y/N message box. However, once I put the code within the ElseIf statement, I receive an "You can't go to specified record." error on the "DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec" part of my public function.

```
Public Function NewEventEntry()
    'this public function creates an empty new record in the subform
    Me![subform_Events].SetFocus
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
End Function


Private Sub RunUpdateQuery_Click()
    'calling the public function works fine here    
    'Call NewEventEntry

If DCount("*", "qry_CheckAllBadAddress") = 0 Then
MsgBox "All addresses are marked bad.", vbExclamation

ElseIf MsgBox("Do you want to update the addres?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Warning") = vbYes Then

    'calling the public function here doesn't work; i receive an error saying: "You can't go to the specified record." the problem is in the public     function, specifically the DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec line
    Call NewEventEntry

End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Me![subform_Events].SetFocus
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
```

How should VBA know, that you want to go to a new Record in the subform, not in the main form? ;-)

Try this:

```
DoCmd.GoToRecord , "subform_Events", acNewRec
```

I'm not sure if this works (long time since I used subforms). If not, I'd try something to do with DAO.recordset

Comment: I've tried that and when that line is entered, it's looking for the subform to actually be open (on its own, rather than be 'open' on the mainform). The 'setfocus' piece is so that the mainform knows to make a new record in the subform (located on the mainform). The line of 'code' works, just not when it's within the ElseIf statement.